# CouchDB view is accessible, but won't run query

Tags: php, database, view, couchdb

I used couchdb's PHP lib to add a view:

```
public function addView() {
    $design_doc = new stdClass();
    $design_doc->_id = '_design/need';
    $design_doc->language = 'javascript';
    $design_doc->views = array( 'all' => array('map' => "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'need')  emit(doc.type, doc) }" ) );
    $result = $this->client->storeDoc($design_doc);
    return $result;
}
```

In my shell, I viewed its doc to confirm it was created:

```
curl -X GET mysite.com/bids/_design/need
{
  "_id":"_design/need",
  "_rev":"1-0ed4b41b839ade9ca36fb950cac1c39b",
  "language":"javascript",
  "views":
    {
      "all":
        {
          "map":"function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'need')  emit(doc.type, doc) }"
        }
    }
}
```

Then when trying to actually execute the view, it throws eacces error:

```
curl -X GET mysite.com/bids/_design/need/_view/all
{
  "error":"error","reason":"eacces"
}
```

**Permissions**: the instance is running as root.

Am I using the wrong syntax to execute the view query?

Could it be that there is an issue with the encoding of the string that was passed via PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue with character encoding by php. Running the exact same query in curl was successful and the view was then able to run properly

Answer (score 3):

"eacces" suggests that it's a problem with the permissions or ownership on the directory your databases are stored in.

For each database, the database server will create a subdirectory called `.<db_name>_design` containing a file for each design document in that database. It's likely that the user your CouchDB instance is running as doesn't have permission to create that directory, or perhaps the file within it.

Check that the directory your databases are in, and everything thereunder, is owned by the user your CouchDB is running as, and that the directories and files have sensible permissions. It's /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb if you installed from source, but will probably be different if you used a package.

Comment: couch is running as root. also, when i deleted the view and re-added it straight from a curl request, it was then functional. maybe php-curl was somehow creating the files with the wrong permissions

Comment: Interesting - my explanation does seem at odds with the fact that CouchDB was running as root. I'm glad it's working, but it would still be interesting to see the couch.log from the time you queried the view and got the error above. I know of no way that php-curl could cause the `.view` files to be created with the wrong permissions, so I don't think that's your explanation.

Comment: I think it really must have something to do with the way that php is char encoding its curl requests...thus forcing the map function to not really be what it looks like... because running the same view PUT request directly in shell works perfectly.